# Braintree credit card integration in android app

Tags: android-studio, braintree, braintree-sandbox

Hello im working on an app in which i want to use braintree credit card integration to accept client payment. I searched but didn't get a proper tutorial. I also searched on braintree developer but its confusing. Please tell me how to do. And most important backend workflow also.

Comment: Hi there, it looks like your question will be more accepted here if you include some code and point out what exception you encounter or which step did you need to understand so that it's easier for us to help you. Anyway, hope you find what you're looking for here and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Agree with @koceeng - in addition if your question is more open-ended, you might have more success contacting Braintree support at support@braintreepayments.com